# Any evolutionary explanation for human blood groups?

Tags: evolution, hematology, blood-group

What is the explanation of people having blood types from an evolutionary perspective?

Comment: I don't think blood group has any selective advantage (except for cases like duffy). IT seems like a neutral polymorphism that remains in the population.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about duffy. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Researchers have puzzled over the selective explanation for the ABO polymorphism at least back to the 1950s. Multiple lines of more recent evidence, including the *very* old age of the ABO polymorphism and (perhaps) multiple convergent evolution events, suggest that the ABO polymorphism is maintained by balancing selection (E.g. [Saitou and Yamamoto 1997](http://mbe.oxfordjournals.org/content/14/4/399.short), [Segurel et al 2012](http://www.pnas.org/content/109/45/18493.abstract)). As best as I know, is no general consensus on what is driving balancing selection, though some researchers have argued that the selective agent is Plasmodium falciparum (e.g. [Cserti and Dzik 2007](http://www.bloodjournal.org/content/110/7/2250?sso-checked=true)).