# Evolution of blood types

Tags: evolution, hematology, molecular-evolution

What are the popular theories regarding how our blood divided into 4 groups. Particularly I'm interested in whether this was originally linked to disease.

Thanks for your answers, useful articles and further reading would also appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Your question is very interesting, however, the general expectation of SE is that you demonstrate that you have researched the topic of your question and have hit a wall in that search, or you are looking for expert advice to explain an advanced topic that you have found that you are having a difficult time explaining. Review [How Do I Ask a Good Question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips and general expectations for the site. Though I personally hope someone can provide an answer as I would be interested in this as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/31920/3340

Comment: yep, sorry for duplicating and thanks for your answers!